# php auto add \ to href

Tags: php

I have this problem with my webpage when I hit the "edit" button, all href adds "\" to the links.

It would keep adding on as the button is hit.

I tested it on xampp-localhost but everything is normal - it only happens when it is hosted.

I am new to php; I tried to Google it, but don't know where to look at, the code below is my edit button's action:

```
if ($img_path!=NULL){
        //delete old image  
        $sql="SELECT image FROM entry WHERE url =?";
        $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array($_POST['url']));
        $e = $stm->fetch();
        if($e['image']!="/simple_blog/img/no_img.jpg"){
            unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$e['image']);
        }

        //update new contain
        $sql = "UPDATE entry SET entry=?, title=?, image=?, url=? WHERE url = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['wall'],$_POST['title'],$img_path,$url,$_POST['url']));
    } elseif ($img_path==NULL){
        $sql = "UPDATE entry SET entry=?, title=?,url=? WHERE url = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['wall'],$_POST['title'],$url,$_POST['url']));
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    header('Location: /simple_blog/blog/'.$_POST['url']);
```

Sorry if I have not explained well about the problem, here is the page you can have a look at, I put the problem in first entry.

[Link  To Blog](http://tblog.comli.com/simple_blog/)

user: testUser

pass: 12345

Thank you very much for any help!

Thank you PleaseStand for the suggestion link :D it's Magic quotes

Just need to add the following code and everything would work fine:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
    unset($process[$key][$k]);
    if (is_array($v)) {
        $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
        $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
    } else {
        $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
    }
}
}
unset($process);
}?>
```

Comment: [Magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)?

Comment: Yes, it's not ``\`` that gets added, it's `\"`. Check for stray quotes on your page.

Comment: Oh, and just some friendly advice: don't rely on W3Schools too much.

Answer (score -1):

sql query is sensitive to question Mark for that put / before it.

for solve this problem you can 
  use This code for read from DB

```
function dbdecode($string){
    $string=str_replace('\\',"\\",$string);
    $string=str_replace("\'","'",$string);
    $string=str_replace("\`","`",$string);
    $string=str_replace('\"','"',$string);
    $string=str_replace('\*','*',$string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this doesn't apply to my problem. I found the answer thank to PleaseStand suggestion :D